# regex - date format OR not specified/empty

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I have a regex problem that I need some advice on.  I am using a jquery plugin that validates input fields on a JSP.  I am using the date validation.  It all works fine but this field is not required and is not marked as required.  When the user hits submit it shows a warning on the date input field since the empty string does not match the validation of a date.  I need some way to say that nothing or a date is valid in a regex.

Here is the regex for the date; is there any way to put "or empty" into this also:

```
"date":{
           "regex":"/^[0-9]{1,2}\-\[0-9]{1,2}\-\[0-9]{4}$/",
           "alertText":"* Invalid date, must be in MM-DD-YYYY format"},
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
/^([0-9]{1,2}\-\[0-9]{1,2}\-\[0-9]{4})?$/
```

It will then match when a valid date is supplied, or the field is left blank.

Answer (score 1):

(^[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{4}$|^$)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply.  When I try that it doesn't do the validation at all and firebug shows me syntax error (^[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{4}$|^$)

Comment: This is a standard regex "alteration" syntax (a|b) means match a or b.  so not sure why you are getting a syntax error.

Comment: me either, I had tried a few options like that already and I was getting the same issue.  I suspect the jquery plugin is funny in terms of what it expects, possibly doesn't like the "or" at all.  Thanks for helping though!

Comment: This failed because the first caret interprets `^[0-9]` to "anything but 0-9"; the `|^$)` was probably not understood as well. In all honesty, I'd never write an optional group like this because a simple question mark after the group makes it optional. (IE, the way my answer's regex was written.)